# How to implement google analytics with Barba.js

Tags: google-analytics, barbajs

I am trying to set up google analytics and Barba.js. I have this analytics code in the footer; see below. I am exporting the code with 'import { analytics } from "./analytics";' using this code below.

I am thenusing 'barba.hooks.enter'. I can see each page in the console log as I click through each click, but google analytics is not recording the page links. Could some please point out what the issue is with the code?

Thank you

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-xxx', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

importing 'import { analytics } from "./analytics";' in app.js. I am using Webpack!

```
const analytics = (container) => {

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        var path = (window.location.href).replace(window.location.origin, '').toLowerCase();
    
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }

        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-xxx', {'page_path': path}); 

        console.log('view sent', path);
}

export default analytics
```

in app.js

```
barba.hooks.enter((data) => {
    analytics();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing code of `analytics.js` library and `gtag.js` library.

If you want to use `analytics.js` you have to use your first code. And you can send custom page in this way:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-xxx', 'auto');
ga('set', 'page', '/about.html');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference

Otherwise the `gtag.js` code, for Universal Analytics, is the following:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-XX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX', {'page_path': '/about.html'});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code and it looks like all is fine, thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Mark answer as solved, pls.